# How do I make git branch work when some git file or directory lost?

Tags: linux, git, git-branch

One day I change a vim configuration from Github(https://github.com/ma6174/vim) on Linux(Visualbox Ubuntu), then some git orders doesn't work.e.g.:

```
git diff
diff-so fancy | less --tabs = 4 RFX: 1: diff-so fancy | less -- tabs = 4 RFX: diff-so:not found 4: No such file or directory
RFX: No such file or directory
```

Also when I input `git branch`, `git log`, it's doesn't work.Just give me something wrong.
But I can use `git add` ,`git commit -m ""`, `git push` to push my file to the remote repository.I also can create a new branch, while can't check the information about dev or master.

Please tell me how to let git work normally.

Comment: It seems likely that you have configured an external diff driver, or perhaps a pager, for Git, then made that not work. But you don't show what you did; you just refer to a GitHub repository about vim.

Comment: When I change vim configuration by only input `wget -qO- https://raw.github.com/ma6174/vim/master/setup.sh | sh -x`.Because I want make vim used easily.But I don't image the change even impacts the git configuration.